# Validar categorias com expressão regular

Tags: php, javascript, delphi, regex, delphi-xe5

Gostaria de saber como faço para validar categorias com expressões regulares. Assim, tenho uma lista de categorias separadas por vírgula. Cada palavra deve ter no máximo 20 caracteres, eu preciso validar a cada vírgula, se a palavra possuí caracteres alfanumericos.

Eu preciso liberar os espaços como eu fiz abaixo, mas a categoria deve ter pelo menos 1 caracter, mas não pode ser feito de espaço.

> nada ,   , olha   ----  Isso não pode acontecer ficar espaço entre as vírgulas.

Comecei fazendo assim:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,20}$
```

> Carro, moto, faca, nada

Alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Realizei testes aqui, e acredito que seja esta a resposta para minha pergunta:

```
^[\s]*[\w]+[\s]*(?:,[\s]*[\w]*[\s]*)*$
```

Mesmo ela aceitando 2 virgulas juntas, eu deixo o usuário errar para depois acertar...

Comment: Mas nesse exemplo: `Carro automático, moto 125, faca cega`, sua expressão regular vai ignorar toda a linha, é realmente isso que procura? Se você pudesse aceitar espaços, fazendo com que `Carro automático` seja um item, você pode usar essa expressão: `[^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]*`

Comment: Então @Gerep , a ideia é esta mesmo, apenas 1 palavra por categoria. Até mais...